# When condition on Circleci 2.1 does not work

Tags: circleci

Recently I've made some configuration on my team's github circleci. I needed to use a `when` statement to devide ci logics. I referenced this document(https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#logic-statements) but it seems the document not correct.

Below is my step definition:

```
...
image_build_step:
    executor: golang_executor
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 18.09.3
          docker_layer_caching: true
      - define_svc_name:
          jobname: ${CIRCLE_JOB}  # On this step set $SVC variable 
      - when: 
          conditon:
            equal: ["${SVC}", "SVC_A" ]
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
                repo: SVC_A_REPO
                dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
                tag: "latest,${CIRCLE_SHA1},build-${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
...
```

Also I already tried this.

```
...
image_build_step:
    executor: golang_executor
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 18.09.3
          docker_layer_caching: true
      - define_svc_name:
          jobname: ${CIRCLE_JOB}  # On this step set $SVC variable 
      - when: 
          equal: ["${SVC}", "SVC_A" ]
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
                repo: SVC_A_REPO
                dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
                tag: "latest,${CIRCLE_SHA1},build-${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
...
```

I cannot figure out my mistake using when statement on circleci. Additionaly, I already passed `circleci config validate .circleci/config.yaml` command before I pushed this commit.

What is the correct usage of `when` statement in circleci? Joining circleci forum is also annoying me using github account, so I leave my question on stakeoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not possible** to use environment variables in logic statements. The reason is that [logic statements are evaluated at configuration compilation time](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference#logic-statements), whereas environment variables are interpolated at run time.

The only workaround I know of is to use the [CircleCI dynamic configuration functionality](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config) to set pipeline parameters' values in the "setup workflow" that you then pass to the "continuation" workflow.